# Proof that a sum is a composite number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need help with the following problem:
Let $p_1, p_2 \geq 5$ be primes such that $6|p_1 - p_2$. Prove that:
$$1^{p_1p_2+1}+2^{p_1p_2+2}+3^{p_1p_2+3}+4^{p_1p_2+4}+5^{p_1p_2+5}+6^{p_1p_2+6}$$ is composite.

Now what I have thought of is if $6|p_1-p_2$ then $p_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ and $p_2 \equiv - 1 \pmod 6$, so $p_1p_2 \equiv -1 \pmod 6$. How do I proceed?

Comment: If $6\mid p_1-p_2,$ then by definition $p_1\equiv p_2\pmod6.$ Then $p_1p_2\equiv 1\pmod6.$

Comment: Do the $p_i$ have to be distinct primes?

Comment: It is easy to show, if $6\not\mid p_1-p_2,$ then $7$ divides this number. Not sure it is true when $6\mid p_1-p_2.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I posted the problem as it is, so $p_i$ are not mentioned as distinct. Should I look at this expression mod 6 and then get 1^0 + 2^2 + ... + 6^5 , which is not divisible by 6 but it is a composite.

Comment: No, you don't get that, because you were wrong that $p_1p_1\equiv-1\pmod 6.$ If $p_1-p_2$ is **not** divisible by $6,$ you do get that expression. You want to look at the expression modulo $7,$ since $a^6=1\pmod7$ for $a=1,2,3,4,5,6.$

Comment: To answer the question about divisibility by $7$. This is not true, because for $p_1=p_2=5$ we obtain the number $1327375129152268704298715$, which is congruent $1$ modulo $7$.

Comment: It is only a small difference between $6\mid p_1-p_2$ and $6\nmid p_1-p_2$ - seen from the typo perspective. Are you sure about it? If $p_1\equiv 1\bmod 6$ and $p_2\equiv -1\bmod 6$, as you tried, then $p_1-p_2\equiv 2\bmod 6$, so certainly not $6\mid p_1-p_2$.

Comment: pbKing, please give a source for the problem so that @DietrichBurde  may see the original text

Comment: @DietrichBurde I found this problem in a Number Theory course my UNI is offering in a PDF file which is a preparation for a midterm so I don't really have a source, but I did copy it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, for simpler algebra, define

$$f(p_1,p_2) = 1^{p_1p_2+1}+2^{p_1p_2+2}+3^{p_1p_2+3}+4^{p_1p_2+4}+5^{p_1p_2+5}+6^{p_1p_2+6} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

As stated in [Thomas Andrews' comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674660/proof-that-a-sum-is-a-composite-number#comment9881524_4674660), requiring $6\mid p_1-p_2$ means that $p_{1}p_{2} \equiv 1\pmod{6}$. Thus, modulo $12$, there are two possibilities. First, if $p_{1}p_{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{12} \;\;\to\;\; p_{1}p_{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then using $a^{4} \equiv 1\pmod{5}$ for $5 \nmid a$ (from [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem)), we get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(p_1,p_2) & \equiv 1^{2} + 2^{3} + 3^{4} + 4^{5} + 5^{6} + 6^{7} \\
& \equiv 1 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 0 + 1 \\
& \equiv 10 \equiv 0 \pmod{5}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Second, there's $p_{1}p_{2} \equiv 7\pmod{12}$. Note that $a^{12} \equiv 1\pmod{13}$ for $13 \nmid a$. Also, $1^6\equiv 3^{6}\equiv 4^{6}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$ and $2^{6}\equiv 5^{6}\equiv 6^{6}\equiv -1\pmod{13}$. Thus,

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(p_1,p_2) & \equiv (1^6)1^2 + (2^6)2^{3} + (3^6)3^{4} + (4^6)4^{5} + (5^6)5^{6} + (6^6)6^{7} \\
& \equiv 1 + (-1)(8) + 3 + 10 + (-1)12 + (-1)7 \\
& \equiv -13 \equiv 0 \pmod{13}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Since $f(p_1,p_2) \gt 13$, from \eqref{eq2A} and \eqref{eq3A}, we get that $f(p_1,p_2)$ is composite for all primes $p_1,p_2 \ge 5$ where $6 \mid p_1-p_2$.

---

Consider the problem condition being $6 \nmid p_1-p_2$ instead, as asked about in [Dietrich Burde's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674660/proof-that-a-sum-is-a-composite-number#comment9881606_4674660) (although the [OP's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674660/proof-that-a-sum-is-a-composite-number/4674725#comment9881859_4674660) confirms the problem was copied correctly, there's still a chance the problem author's intent was otherwise). Then $p_1\equiv 1\pmod{6}$ and $p_2\equiv -1\pmod{6}$, or vice versa, with $p_1p_2 \equiv -1 \pmod{6}$ in either case. Thus, using that $a^6 \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ for all $7 \nmid a$, we then have

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
f(p_1,p_2) & \equiv 1^{0} + 2^{1} + 3^{2} + 4^{3} + 5^{4} + 6^{5} \\
& \equiv 1 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 2 + 6 \\
& \equiv 14 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note this result was also indicated in [Thomas Andrew's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674660/proof-that-a-sum-is-a-composite-number#comment9881541_4674660). Thus, altogether, we've shown that $f(p_1,p_2)$ is composite for *all* primes $p_1,p_2 \ge 5$. More generally, this proves that, for *any* positive integers $p_1$ and $p_2$ with $p_1p_2\equiv\pm 1\pmod{6}$, then $f(p_1,p_2)$ is composite.